# Accessing variables within a botbuilder dialog

Tags: node.js, dialog, botframework, chatbot

I'm building a bot in nodejs where I would like the user to move through different dialog paths dependent on how the interaction started. I'm looking to distinguish between proactive messages, onmembersadded and onmessage.

My idea to do this was to create a variable with the type of interaction (onmessage or onmembersadded) and then pass this through to my main dialog and route from there. Annoyingly I can't find a way to access this variable within the main dialog. Can anyone help me with how to do this or suggest another way of achieving the same goal?

I've looked through a lot of the existing material and I can't find anything attempting the same.

Dialogbot

```
const CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY = 'conversationData';

class TeamsBot extends DialogBot {
    /**
     *
     * @param {ConversationState} conversationState
     * @param {UserState} userState
     * @param {Dialog} dialog
     */
    constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super(conversationState, userState, dialog);

        this.conversationDataAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(context, {});
                    conversationData.trigger = "onNewMemberAdded";
                    console.log(this.dialogState);
                    await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
                }
            }
```

This will then save down the conversationData.trigger but when I then try to access it in mainDialog as below I get a "Conversationstate is not defined" error

```
class MainDialog extends LogoutDialog {
    constructor() {
        super(MAIN_DIALOG);

        this.conversationDataAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);
```

Then within a step

```
const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(context, {});
```

edit:

Thanks for replying. I was initialising main dialog in index.js as follows:

```
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();

// Create conversation and user state with in-memory storage provider.
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

// Create the main dialog.
const dialog = new MainDialog();
// Create the bot that will handle incoming messages.
const bot = new TeamsBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);
```

I think that I can't initialise it in index.js as at this point I don't have the conversationdataAccessors set up (these are done in the bot code as above). I've tried to then change this to not pass through the dialog param to the bot code but this is then difficult to get the dialogs working correctly. Hopefully this helps to answer your question!

Comment: How are you starting main dialog? You need to make sure you are passing your state objects into that dialog as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've updated to show how I was initialising - it was in index.js

Comment: You can access `conversationState` within your bot file, correct? And only in MainDialog it fails? The issue seems to be that you have not passed in your state objects to MainDialog. But I am not quite sure how to solve it since I use activity handler and not a main dialog. I define my dialogs like `this.dialogs.add(new ViewOrderDialog(VIEW_ORDER_DIALOG, this.userDialogStateAccessor, userState, this.appInsightsClient, this.dialogState, conversationState));` (I use "dialogState" as my conversationState accessor name instead of "conversationDataAccessor" as you used)

Comment: I think part of my issue has been that following this example:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/43.complex-dialog/index.js
I had been adding in the main dialog in index.js, before I had defined conversationState. This made it difficult as I want to set values in my bot activity handler and access these in the dialog. Do you have any examples of adding dialogs in the activity handler? I've been trying to do this but now have an issue where my other (not main) dialogs don't progress at all

Comment: So my statement isn't exactly accurate. DialogAndWelcomeBot extends DialogBot which extends ActivityHandler, so this bot is already set up to do this. I use an older method so setting up your dialogs in DialogBot isn't going to work the same way for you. I think I may be on to something though...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need to pass your state objects to the MainDialog's constructor. In the sample you provided, they are doing this but only for user state. You would want to pass conversation state as well. So when you create your MainDialog use:

`const dialog = new MainDialog(userState, conversationState)`

Then you need to update your constructor do handle these:

```js
class MainDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(userState, conversationState) {
        super(MAIN_DIALOG);
        this.userState = userState;
        this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.conversationData = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);
```

Now when you are in MainDialog, you should have access to the conversationState object.

You are already passing conversationState to your TeamsBot, which is extending DialogBot (which extends, I presume, ActivityHandler). You may need to add a save changes statement in TeamsBot, though I'm not 100% sure since this also happens in DialogBot. I guess try it the way it is and if it's not working add an additional save state line inside TeamsBot (e.g. `await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false);`). If you are instead hitting `onMessage` within DialogBot, you already should have the state objects there as well and can just set your onMessage variable in conversationData.